# Using PHP variable in mysql_query string

Tags: php, mysql, variables

OK guys. I have a somewhat complicated issue with passing PHP variables into the mysql_query string.

The $_GET['date']; when passed will contain something like: 2015_01_07_1

I need to have the GET data passed into the table names using the $week variables.

```
<?php

    $week= $_GET['date'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassword","beerhandpoker");
    // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    $result = mysqli_query
    ($con,
        "SELECT games_brixx_gastonia_'$week'.rank, players_brixx_gastonia.name, games_brixx_gastonia_'$week'.points
        FROM games_brixx_gastonia_'$week', players_brixx_gastonia
        WHERE games_brixx_gastonia_'$week'.email = players.email
        ORDER BY games_brixx_gastonia_'$week'.rank
        LIMIT 20"
    );

    echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['rank'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: I know that it is the variable throwing the error because using the query in the sql editor via phpmyadmin, it works fine with 2015_01_07_1 instead of the variable.

Comment: just remove the single quotes around `'$week'` and use braces should be `games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}.rank`. the braces is not needed in your case but it is a good practice to make sure you won't mess with more complex variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the string literal to:

```
"SELECT games_brixx_gastonia_$week.rank,    
players_brixx_gastonia.name,games_brixx_gastonia_$week.points
FROM games_brixx_gastonia_$week, players_brixx_gastonia
WHERE games_brixx_gastonia_$week.email = players_brixx_gastonia.email
ORDER BY games_brixx_gastonia_$week.rank
LIMIT 20"
```

You have to remove the `'` characters;
It's going to the db as `games_brixx_gastonia_'2015_01_07_1'.rank`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. I knew it was something simple and I was just overlooking it.

Comment: Also I do see the other error I made in the syntax where it shows players.email. It should say players_brixx_gastonia.email

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put single quotes? It should work:

```
SELECT games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}.rank, players_brixx_gastonia.name, games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}.points
FROM games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}, players_brixx_gastonia
WHERE games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}.email = players.email
ORDER BY games_brixx_gastonia_{$week}.rank
LIMIT 20
```

Anyway, I'd rather advice you to use statement instead. Check it out:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Yes. I guess it's even useful for code readability and, hopefully, fight SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `'` characters. Otherwise the query would try to get data from the table games_brixx_gastonia_'2015_01_07_1' and not games_brixx_gastonia_2015_01_07_1.